# Wordpress loop with pages

Tags: wordpress, loops

Im pretty new to playing around with what the loop can do and i have been looking for an answer for the last few days. So I have 2 pages services-page.php and contact-page.php both with custom templates. What i would like to know is it possible to set up the loop in page.php to get those custom templates with get_template_part() so when someone goes to the services page it goes to it and same with the contact page. So instead of having a loop on every different page I can just have it in page.php and bring in my different templates which goes to different pages. Hope that was clear, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe i understand what your saying, so create a loop.php to place my loop into then get_template_part() to each different page i set up?

Comment: Yes - but I would create a custom page loop-something.php etc instead rather than loop.php as that should be left for the basic loop if needed. Re use of code is the right way to go :) so you are definitely thinking the right way.

Comment: Also look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts as a function rather than messing with the_query - it is much safer and will work better if you are using it as a template part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there with the get_template_part() but instead you would create a template part for your loop and include that on your templates. So create a php "part" that contains your loop and any other code you need.https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part has an example with "loop.php" but you could create "loop-name.php" (where "name" can be anything you like) for your own loop and use this.